# page is not appearing for keyword in google search

Tags: google-search

our keyword is png compressor and our page is best among all sites but its not appearing even in last result. i have checked all 250-260 results and you wont believe out of 250 results 200 are completely irrelevant like CNG gas, oil company, mobile phone, ingersolrand, GE company etc but my result is not appearing.
we have tried our level best to list keywords in right place but why google is not showing it in last page even ??

is google completely irrelevant now ?? because when users search these things they trust google blindly but showing irrelevant result or omiting other probable result and showing mobile phones,oil companies bla bla is not injustice to users who is trusting google in the hope that they are seeing best results? is not it injustice to developers who is doing hard work to create something useful but ultimately being killed by google?

We are not new and so we think we must appear in search and for users perspective also we are far better for compress png keyword compared to oil company,mobile phones etc.

please guide if you can why we are not appearing in search

Comment: Who says your page is better than all sites?

Comment: First things first. You are trying to compete in a highly competitive search market. Second, you assume too much. PNG stands for pipeline natural gas which is compressed. As well, PNG stands for Papua New Guinea where PNG gas was first used. None of these are irrelevant if you are in the petroleum industry. Only irrelevant to you. Being only two search terms, your search query contains almost no semantic clues and therefore disambiguation is not possible. This is a good example of why the keyword chase is completely bogus. Search is about whole language which is how a site is found. Cheers!!